# One lab, multiple robots, multiple independent projects

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just came across this quote:

"For use cases with multiple robots it is generally recommended to use multiple masters and forward specific tf information between the robots. There are several different methods of implementing bridges between masters. For more information please see the sig/Multimaster."

In my case, we have a small robotics lab with around 10 robots. Students pair up and each are assigned a robot. Obviously we want the different student projects not to interfere with each other. We are currently running a single roscore.

The above quote (from the tf2 documentation) implies some problems with what we are doing. I need a little help clarifying or elaborating on the above caveat as well as the "right" way to do what I am trying to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326592/one-lab,-multiple-robots,-multiple-independent-projects/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should run a separate roscore for each robot. I usually run the roscore on the robot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-06-21**:
Can you say why? What problems does it solve? What problems does it create? Right now I have it working apparently fine with name spacing. Thanks.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-06-21**:
Running a separate roscore for each robot doesn't require namespacing or TF prefixes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:\

> Obviously we want the different student projects not to interfere with each other.

And it also automatically isolates each robot -- and connected ROS nodes -- from each other.

Nothing prevents anyone from using the namespace of a different robot and mucking things up.

Using a separate master makes this much harder (not impossible, as it's a form of security-through-obscurity, but still).

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-06-22**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn. Much better than actual answer. My robots have just a raspberry pi. Would running core on them be a cpu or memory load problem do you think?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:
A master does not use significant amounts of CPU, it should be fine.

Unless students start using parameters as topics -- which I have seen -- but that would obviously be a no-no in any case.